# How to provide input to an injective type function

Tags: haskell, ghc

In my application, I'm building up an expression whose type is an (injective) function of some parameter `d`. For example:

```
op :: Proxy d -> Proxy ('S d)
op _ = Proxy

foo :: forall d . Proxy ('S ('S d))
foo = op $ op Proxy
```

After I've built up an expression like `foo`, I'd like to interpret it:

```
getValue :: Proxy (d :: Nat) -> Int
getValue _ = ...
```

To interpret `foo`, I could call `getValue $ foo @'Z`, using type-applications syntax. That's just fine, except my intent is to always call `getValue` with this pattern. Thus rather than making the *user* always have to specify that their expression is relative to `'Z`, I'd prefer it if this property were instead inherent in `getValue`, so that I can write `getValue foo` and would presumably get back `2`.

NB: One solution is to make the input to the function input explicit with a `Proxy`: `foo :: Proxy d -> Proxy ('S ('S d))` and `getValue :: (Proxy d1 -> Proxy d2) -> Int`, and then have `getValue` apply the function to `'Z`. This achieves what I want, but the extra `Proxy` is annoying. Is there a way that does not require this extra `Proxy`?

Comment: Just curious: why not just use singletons?

Comment: I'm already using singletons in a wrapper around my `Nat` value, so it'd be no trouble at all, if you want to suggest an approach.

Comment: The problem is `Proxy :: Proxy t`, but you want `_Z :: Proxy 'Z` - so just define such a constant yourself. If you really must move this work to `getValue`, then you can use instance overlap to instantiate "free" type variables to `'Z`, but it really isn't worth it.

Comment: @user2407038 Not sure what you mean by "the problem is `Proxy::Proxy t`". There's no need to define any values if I use type applications.

Comment: @crockeea If the type of `foo` was `Proxy (S (S Z))` you would have no problem. So give it this type, by defining it as `op (op (Proxy :: Proxy 'Z))` instead of `op (op (Proxy :: Proxy t))`. Then, presumably, you do not want to have to specify the type everywhere, so you define a constant `_Z :: Proxy 'Z` to save yourself some typing.

Comment: @user2407038 Point taken. An even easier way is to just put the `'Z` in the types signature. The point, however, (possibly not obvious in my simplified example) is to keep `foo` polymorphic so that it can continue to be composed with other subexpressions.

Answer (score -2):

Rename your `getValue` to `getValue'` and write `getValue foo = getValue' $ foo @'Z`.

```
getValue :: (forall (d :: Nat). Proxy d) -> Int
getValue foo = getValue' $ foo @'Z

getValue' :: Proxy (d :: Nat) -> Int
getValue' Proxy = ...
```

Here's a better way to reify natural numbers if that is your end goal:

```
class ReifyNat (n :: Nat) where
  reifyNat :: Integer

instance ReifyNat 'Z where
  reifyNat = 0

instance ReifyNat n => ReifyNat ('S n) where
  reifyNat = succ (reifyNat @n)

getValue :: forall n. ReifyNat n => Proxy n -> Integer
getValue _ = reifyNat @n
```

Or just use:

```
getValue :: forall n. ReifyNat n => Integer
getValue = reifyNat
```

You can probably get rid of *all* your uses of `Proxy` in this way if you wish.

Comment: I figure your first line couldn't possible work, could it? We'd have to tell the compiler that `getValue`s argument can take a type application. What is the type of your `getValue`?

Comment: The point here is not to reflect the value of a `Nat` (that's just an example). The point is to provide an input to a type function automatically when calling `getValue`. Your first approach would do the trick, if it indeed compiles.

Comment: @crockeea Your problem appears to be the specific case of the more general "How to make `f x y` always use some specific `y` instead of taking it as an argument?" The answer is to make a function `f' x = f x someFixedY`. You might have to add an explicit `forall`: `getValue' :: forall (n :: Nat). Int`. You just move the type argument from a value level proxy lambda to a type level uppercase lambda.

Comment: @Lazersmoke Note that `getValue foo` won't compile. I think this answer is missing the point of the question - the signature of `getValue` you propose won't help. `forall p. Proxy p` obliterates any hope of recovering the "at least two" nature of `foo`. I reckon the real answer to this question is "this isn't possible".